# How can I get a hibernate PersistentObjectException without even a relation

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am trying to test some persistence with Quarkus-Panache and an H2 in memory database and I am experiencing an unexpected Hibernate issue with detached entities when I try to create a new entity. The entity does not entail any relationship. (I am using the the repository pattern.)

Her is the simple Panache Entity:

```
package ws.prager.student;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntityBase;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and a repository

```
package ws.prager.student;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheRepository;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class StudentRepository implements PanacheRepository<Student> {
}
```

, executing the test class:

```
package ws.prager.student;

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@QuarkusTest
class StudentRepositoryTest {

    @Inject
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Test
    void findAll() {
        List<Student> students = studentRepository.listAll();
        assertNotNull(students);
        assertFalse(students.isEmpty());
        assertEquals(1L, students.get(0).getId());
        assertEquals("Jane", students.get(0).getName());

    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void persist() {
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setId(2L);
        s.setName("Joe");
        studentRepository.persist(s);
    }

}
```

throws a

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: ws.prager.student.Student
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: ws.prager.student.Student
```

on the persist test.
Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/bprager/53840cc869e93caf4ccefc5e062e37e0

Could anyone please give me a hint what I am missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue apparently was providing an ID for the created object in the test, while having the Entity declared with a @GeneratedValue. Not setting the ID allowed the test to pass.